# Why do t statistics decrease (standard error for cofficient increases) when multicollinearity exists?

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

Can anybody show how the t statistic decreases when multicollinearity exists? It is easy to prove using the F test, but I don't know how to prove it using the t test.

Comment: (hint) If you know how to do it for the F test can't you use the relationship between the t-distribution and the F-distribution? I.e., $t^2=F(1,\nu_2)$

Comment: Look at the formula for the standard error... And see how it is effected by multicollinearity.

Comment: It may be a bit of a challenge even to define this question well: "decreases" with respect to what?  Precisely which aspect(s) of the situation--model, regressors, responses--do you suppose is changing as "non-multicollinearity" progresses to "multicollinearity"?